# Using ParamArray in VB.Net passing Object Or Array of Objects as Argument

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm having a brain fart.

I'm trying to set up a function that can take in an object as its arguments. This function should output a data table. Here is what I have so far and is not functional.

**DEFINED INPUT**

```
'Example 1
GetDataTableWithParams("..myStoredProcedure", {333, SqlDbType.Int, "@UserID"})

'Example 2
GetDataTableWithParams("..myStoredProcedure", [{333, SqlDbType.Int, "@UserID"}, {9090, SqlDbType.Int, "@ProfileID"}]
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
'Example 1
Dim params(0) As IDataParameter
params(0) = Data.GetDataParameter(333, 8, "@UserID")

'Example 2
Dim params(1) As IDataParameter
params(0) = Data.GetDataParameter(333, 8, "@UserID")
params(1) = Data.GetDataParameter(9090, 8, "@ProfileID")
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

```
'Example 1
params(0) DataAction.GetDataParameter(333
params(1) DataAction.GetDataParameter(8
params(2) DataAction.GetDataParameter(@UserID
```

**My Function**

```
Public Function GetDataTableWithMultipleParams(ByVal _StoredProcedure As String, ByVal ParamArray _Params() As Object) As DataTable

        If _Params.Length <= 1 Then Exit Function

            Dim params(_Params.Length) As IDataParameter

            For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(_Params, 1)
                Console.WriteLine("params(" & i & ") " & "DataAction.GetDataParameter(" & _Params(i), ")")
            Next


        'Dim table As DataTable = DataAction.GetDataTableParametrized(_StoredProcdure, CommandType.StoredProcedure, params)
        'Return table

End Function
```

Comment: This is a basic problem with your algorithm.  It's doing exactly what you told it to do, without any surprises.  What's not clear is why you would ever expect that code to output the "expected output".

Comment: First problem is that you have the parameter set to be an array of objects, but you want to call it, in the second case, with an array of object arrays.

Comment: What would be far preferable, I'd think, would be to create a class that has the three properties, then you could just have it take a ParamArray of that class.  No 2D array needed.  And then you wouldn't need to overload it either.

Comment: So from your suggestion. It would make more sense to create a class with this method. I know I may not be explaining as clearly as I can but bear with me. I'm trying to avoid overloading this method as the number of arguments may vary.
Also, this is a contrived function as I'm NOT actually expecting the output to be what I posted.

Comment: This function is suppose to return a DataTable and the for loop is expected to build the parameters and pass that as an argument to the DataAction.GetDataTableParametrized Method.

Answer (score 1):

The following is what Steven D is proposing (I assume anyway). I hope you understand it ok.

```
    Option Explicit On

    Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            ''Example2
            myStoredProcedure({New HoldItems(Value:=333, SqlType:=SqlDbType.Int, Name:="@UserID"),
                              New HoldItems(Value:=9090, SqlType:=SqlDbType.Int, Name:="@ProfileID")})
        End Sub

        Public Sub myStoredProcedure(ByVal ParamArray _Params() As Object)
            Dim _class As HoldItems
            Dim intI As Integer

            For intI = 0 To UBound(_Params)
                _class = DirectCast(_Params(intI), HoldItems)

                Debug.Print("Name=" & _class.Name & " Value=" & _class.Value & " SqlType=" & _class.SqlType)
            Next intI
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class HoldItems
        Public Value As Integer
        Public SqlType As Integer
        Public Name As String

        Public Sub New(Value As Integer, SqlType As SqlDbType, Name As String)
            Me.Value = Value
            Me.SqlType = SqlType
            Me.Name = Name
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Thanks @IAmNerd2000, I extended your idea by making HoldItems.Value into an object rather than specifically an integer, so that it can be used with any SqlDbType.